# Confusing transformer winding, what is it and can i change it?

Tags: voltage, transformer, electromagnetism, step-down

here are two 380V to 24V/48v transformers that weigh 10 pounds each.

I was hoping i could get 15V with 500w out of one at 240V and measure the welding potential.

the secondary winding uses 0.5mm copper, it seems a small gauge to achieve 24v? can i take out half of the secondary windings to achieve 7v?

How many windings and what gauge of copper should i use to replace the secondary coil?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wire gauge does not determine output voltage

Answer (score 1):

Merely applying 240V to the 380V winding will give you about 15V out on the 24V winding (full load voltage). Take all appropriate precautions.

Though I have no way of knowing what the ratings are on the transformer, it does not look like it is suitable for much in the way 'welding' unless you're thinking of doing it under a magnifier.

Comment: Thanks. The input for the 380v and the output for the 24v are both about 0.5mm. does that mean that the transformer could never safely supply more than 350 watts without getting too hot? I want to solder some 0.2mm nickel strips so 350 watts would be fine.

Comment: if i manage to get precisely the same voltage from them i could use them in parallel an achieve 500watts maximum output. I don't understand how the output would be regulated. i would be using it bursts of 1-2 seconds and less. The sticker sais IP=003, CL=1.

Comment: The wattage is fairly academic. You can briefly exceed the rating of the transformer in a welding situation if you don't let it overheat. If the weld is too low resistance all the heat ends up in the transformer, if the voltage is too low you won't get enough current to make a weld. Yes, you may be able to parallel the transformers if they are identical (they do **not** look identical), but the potential for problems is there. Get the phase wrong and they'll both self destruct fairly quickly.